# LCD1602 not displaying any characters

Tags: arduino, lcd, interface

I've connected an Arduino with a LCD1602. I've followed this exact tutorial:

[Link to the tutorial](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/najad/interfacing-lcd1602-with-arduino-764ec4)

Whenever I see my LCD at a right angle (upfront) I can't see anything. But whenever I see my screen sideways from the top I can see the characters.

What's wrong?

[image: Front-facing view]

[image: Side view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did exactly what the tutorial said, it is quite a miracle that there is anything visible at all.

The contrast pin should not be directly connected to ground. Connecting it directly to ground sets the contrast to maximum and everything is just black.

That is very poor quality tutorial. As always, some healthy critique is in order and before frying up something, always use a second source to back things up.

Solution, put a 10k pot to adjust the contrast pin voltage between VCC and GND.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pin for the contrast adjustment. We usually connect it to a potentiometer in order to regulate the contrast. It is marked V0 on the LCD pinout in your tutorial.